# Why is a defined variable in try/catch block showing undefined in the same function scope?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, undefined

This code is part of a javascript course I am doing. And this exercise was in the error handling part where I needed to guess the output.

Code:

```js
(function () {
  try {
    throw new Error();
  } catch (err) {
    var err = 5;   //creating another local err variable
    var boo = 10;
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(err);
  console.log(boo);
})();
```

Output:

```
5  
undefined   //I don't understand this part  
10
```

The error is passed as a parameter `err`  in the catch block. But with `var`, the `err` variable gets overwritten. So instead of logging the error, `5` gets logged in the first `console.log(err)`.

But I couldn't figure out why the second `console.log(err)` outputs `undefined`. As far as I understood, `var` is not block-scoped, so, inside the same function scope, I should have access to the `err` variable. And, due to hoisting, `var` becomes undefined initially. But as `try/catch` block is **synchronous** and I am logging the variable after defining it, **shouldn't it log `5`?** Because `console.log(boo)` returned `10` as expected.

**Is it due to creating the variable with the same name as the local parameter?**

*NB: This is my first question on stackoverflow. So forgive any mistake!*

Comment: The catch exception variable is only available inside the catch block: This: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#the_exception_identifier

Comment: A quick Google search yielded [this](https://medium.com/@sarbbottam/the-curious-case-of-variable-declarations-inside-a-catch-block-891a4369aaf0). My head hurts from reading it.

Comment: I didn't know the spec hat places, where there are [alternatives](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-try-statement-static-semantics-early-errors) to choose when wanted. Maybe i am also just misinterpreting, what i am reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that `var` is function scoped and not block scoped, however there's an exception for catch blocks if the `var` declaration has the same name as a catch block bound variable such that the shadowed `var` declaration will not be lifted to the function scope.

Relevant piece of the spec:
https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#prod-annexB-CatchParameter

> The Block of a Catch clause may contain var declarations that bind a name that is also bound by the CatchParameter. At runtime, such bindings are instantiated in the VariableDeclarationEnvironment. They do not shadow the same-named bindings introduced by the CatchParameter and hence the Initializer for such var declarations will assign to the corresponding catch parameter rather than the var binding.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be accepted.

Comment: I was still a little bit confused about the exception bindings, but reading this [link](https://medium.com/@sarbbottam/the-curious-case-of-variable-declarations-inside-a-catch-block-891a4369aaf0) given by Lil Devil really clarified my concept. Thank you. It makes sense now.